# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, flask, pytest

Test file:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    db_fd, dp_path = tempfile.mkstemp()
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with app.test_client() as cl:
        with app.app_context():
            yield cl
    os.close(db_fd)

def test_auth(client):
    payload = {
        'username': 'testing',
        'password': 'hard_pass'
    }
    resp = client.post('/login', data=jsonify(payload))
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

In views.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    return 'Test passed'
```

And then i have an error:

```
d = <Response 46 bytes [200 OK]>, args = (), kwargs = {}

>   iteritems = lambda d, *args, **kwargs: iter(d.items(*args, **kwargs))
E   AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'items'

blog_env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_compat.py:135: AttributeError
```

I know that Response object in Flask doesn`t have 'items'. But what can i do to fix this problem? 
Full Traceback:

```
client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'blog_app'>>

    def test_auth(client):
        payload = {
            'username': 'testing',
            'password': 'hard_pass'
        }
>       resp = client.post('/login', data=jsonify(payload))

server\tests\test_client.py:30:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
blog_env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py:1016: in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
blog_env\lib\site-packages\flask\testing.py:215: in open
    builder = EnvironBuilder(self.application, *args, **kwargs)
blog_env\lib\site-packages\flask\testing.py:86: in __init__
    super(EnvironBuilder, self).__init__(path, base_url, *args, **kwargs)
blog_env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py:402: in __init__
    for key, value in _iter_data(data):
blog_env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py:220: in _iter_data
    for key, values in iteritems(data):
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

d = <Response 46 bytes [200 OK]>, args = (), kwargs = {}

>   iteritems = lambda d, *args, **kwargs: iter(d.items(*args, **kwargs))
E   AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'items'

blog_env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_compat.py:135: AttributeError
================================================================================ short test summary info =================================================================================
FAILED server/tests/test_client.py::test_auth - AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Well, what kind of object do you think the test is expecting to receive?

Comment: @gold_cy No problem

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Response? Speak honestly i copied this code from flask documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.
Problem was with:

```
data=jsonify(payload)
```

For some reasons it didn`t work. I removed jsonify and test passed successful

Edited:
Because

```
jsonify(payload)
```

create

```
<Response 46 bytes [200 OK]>
```

And in this way data contains Response object instead of json.

I had to notice it before because code stopped on 'client.post' line